# Disable user input until Thread.sleep() finishes

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

I'm writing a really basic program, but I've run into a problem. The following is a slice of my code (it is a really silly program, don't try to guess what I'm using it for.)

```
System.out.println("Please press the Return button a 1000 times.");
    for(int i = 1;i < 25;i++) {
        input.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Stop! Stop! Jeez, that was a joke! Do you think I'd make you press that button a 1000 times?");
    try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    System.out.println("Let's move on.");
```

What would happen here is that the program asks the user to press the Return button a 1000 times, which the user would eventually start spamming. The main problem is that after I declare that it was a joke and he only needed to press it 25 times, I'd like to disable the user input, as it's likely that the user will press the button multiple times before realizing that I was just joking. But when the thread.sleep is running, the user input is still active, which leads to multiple problems.

So, is there any way to disable the user input while the program is sleeping?

Answer (score 1):

You can control what to read from the console via application.. But to disable input entirely will be dependent on type of environment application is running on ... For E.g. in cmd line it should not allow you to type in after 25 enters... Whereas in IDE like eclipse, you can type in on console but it will not be read by application after 25 lines.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that it is enough to add 1 line to your code (james large suggestion):

```
System.out.println("Let's move on.");
System.in.read(new byte[System.in.available()]);//read and ignore
```

Comment: That's straightforward, but it's highly system dependant how System.in behaves exactly. Sometimes available() just returns always 0 (InputStream default implementation, see Javadoc).

Comment: The available() method should *never* be used to guess the available inputs size, its completely implementation dependent how the actual amount of input available and the returned amount correlate. While it may work perfectly fine in some settings, its one of those misuses that come to bite you when you least expect it at the most inconvinient time.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this:

```
public class Main {    

private static final String QUIT = "quit";
private static final int COUNT = 1000;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new Main(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))).main();
}

private final BufferedReader in;
private final BlockingQueue<String> lines = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);
private volatile boolean ignore;

public Main(BufferedReader in) {this.in = in;}

private void main() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread inputReader = new Thread(this::read, "input-reader");
    inputReader.setDaemon(true);        
    System.out.println("Please press the Return button a "+COUNT+" times.");
    inputReader.start();
    String line = "";
    for(int i = 1;i <= 25;i++) {
        line = lines.take();
        System.out.println("Good! You entered '"+line+"'. Only "+(COUNT-i)+" left.");
    }
    System.out.println("Stop! Stop! Jeez, that was a joke! Do you think I'd make you press that button a "+COUNT+" times?");
    ignore = true;
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    ignore = false;
    String optionalLine = lines.poll();
    if(optionalLine!=null) {
        line = optionalLine; System.out.println("Ignored:" + line);
    }
    System.out.println("Let's move on. Type "+QUIT+" when you're tired.");
    while(!QUIT.equalsIgnoreCase(line)){
        line = lines.take();
        System.out.println(">"+line);
    }
    System.out.println("Bye.");
}

private void read(){
    try {
        String line = in.readLine();
        while(line!=null){
            if (ignore) {
                boolean inserted = lines.offer(line);
                if (!inserted)
                    System.out.println("Ignored:" + line);
            } else {lines.put(line);}
            line = in.readLine();
        }        
    } catch (IOException|InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}

}
```